# Using Angularjs to pull 2 different JSON files

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

So I have 2 JSON file examples I need to incorporate, but being that the format of each is different, I trying to figure the best way using an angular controller to deal with these. These are not coming through an API, but as pure JSON files stored in my project. I had intended to loop through these using ng-repeat.

The JSON files:

```
window.__BATMAN_DATA__ = {
    "1806 E. Wayne Lane, Fort Dodge, IA 50501": {
        "cost": "849,950",
        "beds": "5",
        "baths": "3",
        "sq_ft": "4050",
        "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
        "url": "http://trulia.com"
    },
    "1774 Kapow Drive, Hyattsville, MD 20782": {
        "cost": "419,950",
        "beds": "3",
        "baths": "2",
        "sq_ft": "1700",
        "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
        "url": "http://trulia.com"
    },
    "773 Duhnuhnuhna Street, Essex, MD 21221": {
        "cost": "524,999",
        "beds": "3",
        "baths": "2",
        "sq_ft": "1980",
        "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
        "url": "http://trulia.com"
    },
    "178 Pennyworth Avenue, Depew, NY 14043": {
        "cost": "619,999",
        "beds": "4",
        "baths": "1.5",
        "sq_ft": "2100",
        "img": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
        "url": "http://trulia.com"
    }
};
```

and:

```
window.__SUPERMAN_DATA__ = {
    "items": [
        {
            "address": "7791 Luther Way, Knoxville, TN 37918",
            "price": "549999",
            "beds": "3",
            "baths": "2.5",
            "sqft": "3000",
            "built": "1976",
            "thumb": "http://fillmurray.com/150/150",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        },
        {
            "address": "1774 Kapow Drive, Hyattsville, MD 20782",
            "price": "419950",
            "beds": "3",
            "baths": "2",
            "sqft": "1700",
            "built": "2001",
            "thumb": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        },
        {
            "address": "3121 5th Street, Gotham, NY 27520",
            "price": "280000",
            "beds": "2",
            "baths": "1",
            "sqft": "",
            "built": "1948",
            "thumb": "http://fillmurray.com/150/150",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        },
        {
            "address": "178 Pennyworth Avenue, Depew, NY 14043",
            "price": "619999",
            "beds": "4",
            "baths": "1.5",
            "sqft": "2100",
            "built": "2014",
            "thumb": "http://stevensegallery.com/200/200",
            "url": "http://zillow.com"
        }
    ]
};
```

Comment: And what is your question? You are only using statements.

Comment: Re-read it and you will see. Asking about combing different JSON formats.

Answer (score 0):

Something along those lines perhaps?

```
$scope.items = [];

$http.get('file1.json').then(function(response){
    angular.forEach(response.data.__BATMAN_DATA__, function(value,key){
        $scope.items.push({ 
            address: key, 
            image : value.img,
            ...              
        });
    })
});

$http.get('file2.json').then(function(response){
    angular.forEach(response.data.__SUPERMAN_DATA__, function(value,key){
        $scope.items.push({ 
            address: value.address, 
            image : value.thumb
            ...
        });
    })
});
```

Not tested because lazy questions gets lazy answers :p

Comment: Was not intended to be a lazy question. I knew about this part, but coming the 2 JSON files together so that they can be called as one in an ng-repeat is what I was trying to trigger.